# WeldClientProxy cannot be cast

Tags: cdi, weld, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I use the Unbound ID library that has a class LDAPConnection which has no default constructor and which implements LDAPInterface. I produce the LDAPConnection as follows:

```
@Produces
@SimpleLdapConnection
@ApplicationScoped
public LDAPInterface createLdapConnection() throws GeneralSecurityException, LDAPException {
    LDAPConnection conn = new LDAPConnection(host, port, username, password);
    return conn;
}
```

I now want to inject this LDAPConnection class to a second producer, which should generate a Connection Pool:

```
@Inject
@SimpleLdapConnection
LDAPInterface simpleLdapConnection;

@Produces
@Default
@ApplicationScoped
public LDAPInterface produceLdapConnectionPool() throws GeneralSecurityException, LDAPException {
    LDAPConnectionPool pool = new LDAPConnectionPool((LDAPConnection)simpleLdapConnection.g, connectionPoolInitialSize, connectionPoolMaxSize);
    return pool;
}
```

To create the LDAPConnectionPool, I need to cast the simpleLdapConnection to an LDAPConnection (as it must be an LDAPConnection).

However, I get the error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.jboss.weld.proxies.LDAPInterface$1687649628$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
>   cannot be cast to com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnection
>
> at
>   at.rsg.lp.benutzerverwaltung.business.repository.LdapConnectionPoolProvider.produceLdapConnectionPool(LdapConnectionPoolProvider.java:59)

How can I get around this error?
P.S. changing the first producer to return an LDAPConnection does not work as I get the error "Injected normal scoped bean is not proxyable".

Comment: The problem seems to be caused by the fact that LDAPConnection is final. This forces Weld to create such a proxy. One (albeit ugly) solution is to write a non-final wrapper class.

Comment: Do you really need the `LDAPConnection` exposed as a CDI bean? If not you can simply hide its existence within `produceLdapConnectionPool()`, i.e. the `new LDAPConnection(...)` occurs within that method, you use the local variable to create the `LDAPConnectionPool` and forget about it.

Comment: Thinking a bit more the wrapper you mention, which is of course a viable solution, might not be that ugly after all. Actually, creating a "wrapper" *layer* of objects on top of the Unbound ID API might be a good idea that will uncouple your implementation from it and might even yield more benefits, e.g. testability/mock-ability. At the cost of more code of course.

Comment: Exposing the `LDAPConnection` as a bean is not really necessary, but I then come to a similar problem when using produceLdapConnectionPool. There are reason why I need to cast to that one too, and then again such an exception occurs. So wrapper is probably the way to go...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are running into, from CDI point of view, are the defined bean types of a producer method. This is backed by [CDI specification](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#producer_method_types).

In short, for producer methods, the bean types are derived from return types and the interfaces it implements. E.g. the actual implementation type is *not* included. The reason for that is exactly what you see when you saw when you tried to return the actual implementation type - impls often contain `final` methods or other bumps making them [unproxyable](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#unproxyable).

There are two things I can think of to solve this:

1. <s>[*This one is likely to fail*] Try putting `@Typed` annotation on your producer - I doubt it will work in this case, but it could be worth a shot. This annotation declares all the types the bean will have. You would use it like this - `@Typed({LDAPInterface, LDAPConnection})`.</s>
2. [*This should be a go-to option*] If I were you, I would create a wrapper object just like you suggested. It won't really be all that ugly, just few bits and pieces of code should do the trick.

Comment: 1) sounds like a good idea, but as you assumed, it does not work (the same ClassCastException occurs). 2) works of course.